# Fabric.js - Moving an object under the selected object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have 2 objects (images) in my canvas.

`fc.item(0)` is a smaller image in the middle of the canvas. `fc.item(1)` is a large image, "frame". The user can't move it. When the user's trying to move the `fc.item(1)`, I wanna move the `fc.item(0)`, as if the user's moved on the `fc.item(1)`.

Any idea, how can I do this? I tried to use the `fc.item(0).fire("object:moving")`, but this didn't work well.

Comment: If i understand right, the solution is to move your lower indexed object manually while the selected object is moving. Find the diff (x,y) of the item1 center and add them to item0 center.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to make top object unselectable just set its "selectable" to `false`.

```
fc.item(1).selectable = false;
```

If you *also* want to **propagate events** to the bottom object (essentially "ignoring" top one), set top one's "evented" property to `false`.

```
fc.item(1).evented = false;
```

Comment: Oh damn, I used the fabric.js 1.2 :D

Comment: thanks, i'm using 1.7.3 and needed to disable controls on an object but still have it be selectable